# Outlook add-in not displayed in Mac OS

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We found that our Add-in cannot work on the latest Mac OS (High Sierra 10.13.1). Our outlook version is 15.40. The Add-in cannot be loaded correctly. The Add-in uses AngularJS.  It looks the ngview of the AngularJS cannot be run correctly. We don't know how to do further analysis with such error. Do you know if the outlook has a place to see the error like the browser's development mode to see the console information?

We use script below to bootstrap angular, I might think some error raised that block those scripting from executing.

```
    requirejs(['office'], function () {
        Office.initialize = function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['tor']);
        };
    });
```

BTW, the add-in can work well on the Outlook online (OWA) on the Safari. The add-in can work well on the Outlook on the previous Mac OS (Sierra).

Find more clues during debug:
I added a otherwise route like below:

```
   $routeProvider
        .when('/login/:tenantId/:addinType', {
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }).when('/main/:tenantId/:addinType', {
            templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl',
            caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'book.html'
        });
```

It turns out it always goes to otherwise route and show book.html, the url configured in my manifest file is

```
https://localhost:4004/#!/test
```

Comment: We might found the culprit, I open an another post to track this issue at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074433/outlook-add-in-not-work-with-angular-routing-under-mac-oshigh-sierra-10-13-1). Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Following command enables debugging for webkit which is used on outlook to host webbed-ins

defaults write NSGlobalDomain WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true

After successfully running the command and restarting outlook inspect element option should be available in context menu upon right clciking  in task-pane

Comment: Thanks, but I used vorlon.js to debug as described at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac?product=outlook)